# What's the limit of "soil" for the Prestidigitation cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

This question is about the [*prestidigitation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) cantrip.

It is not obvious to me what I can do with it, which is why I'm asking what the limits are to soiling objects in 1 foot cubic area.

> What are the material limits to soiling an object with the prestidigitation cantrip?

**To soil an object is to make something dirty or unclean.** If you add a foreign substance, it can be considered dirty, whether that's dirt, mud, or even smudged food.

It's a cantrip, and I understand I can't just make something soiled in anything I want, but it doesn't say "soil an object with dirt." Also, it doesn't say, it cannot be soiled by anything either. So the limits are unclear to me.

Comment: I see you deleted the part where you explained what you were trying to do. Which version of this do you want answered?

Comment: @MarkWells the poison wasn't meant to be part of the question, just to give an example to help understand my question. I think your answer gives me about half of what i need, but after rewriting the question to try to clear it up and thinking about it, I think i have my answer. The main thing i would say helps, is to think of it as a cosmetic change (like you said). it's soiling it with whatever material, but it only looks soiled. it doesn't affect the other senses, and the material isn't actually on the pants. Although you would still need to clean it later. Correct me if i'm wrong though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### All the effects of prestidigitation are cosmetic.

It makes tiny objects, lights, sounds, or smells. It draws shapes or marks on things. Its effects are brief, superficial, and innocuous. It should be impossible to weaponize as anything other than a distraction.

The "soil an object" effect doesn't say you get to choose any specific substance to soil it with. Your intent here isn't to "soil" the arrow anyway; it's to *create poison*.

Prestidigitation does have a "create things" mode: it will make a non-magical object that fits in your hand, but the object only lasts for one round. So you could create poison, maybe even on a weapon, but the poison will cease to exist a few seconds later. Even if you do manage to get it into your enemy by then, there won't be time for the poison to do much.

Comment: That is my intent with my example, but that's why i'm trying to clarify what counts as soiling an object. If i don't know what i can soil something with, then it becomes more frustrating trying to use it, only to be shot down by the DM. a poisoned blade could be considered soiled, so cleaning it of the poison would just turn it into a normal blade. so i had to ask myself, why not the opposite?

Comment: @dakre18: "[Soil](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/soil)" (as a verb) has a straightforward meaning in English: "to make unclean, dirty, or filthy, especially on the surface", or "to smirch, smudge, or stain". A poisoned blade isn't "soiled"; it's poisoned. (I think the answer would be improved by referencing the dictionary meaning.)

Comment: @V2Blast i did. I said i know the definition for soil is to make unclean or dirty. that doesn't mean anything to me, because it's vague. a poisoned blade is poisoned, but it's not clean either, assuming it's poison-dipped, not magically poisoned or using an internal hollow area to hold poison. If an object is covered with a foreign substance, it can be considered unclean or dirty.

That's why i'm asking, what are the limits to what you can soil an object with. It may seem obvious to others, but it's not to me. Outside of making something dirty with something like dirt or mud.

Comment: @dakre18 You can see for yourself that the spell doesn't define "soil", so the exact boundaries are up to you and your DM to figure out. I'm just answering in terms of the general pattern of what Prestidigitation can do. It's a spell for making special effects.

Comment: If it helps, consider it to be something you'd deal with in the course of household cleaning or laundry in-universe.

Comment: @MarkWells You seem to contradict "it should be impossible to weaponize" by addressing a potential way to weaponize and saying it may be possible, and this generally gets away from the actual question about "soiling" (the current version seems to have dropped the poison example). Still a helpful answer that got my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Soil has no D&D definition, so it falls to the English language definition of soiled.

The English definition of soiled according to the Google result is to make dirty or unclean(the definitions of which just loop around to soiled), so anything that is considered dirt (By the DM) can be created with this ability.

However, if you want something a bit more objective (read: less dependant on DM), then two more synonyms for dirty/soiled/unclean are fouled and polluted.
Other than the meanings in social contexts, Foul means offensive to the senses, and Polluted means containing something harmful or poisonous.

So you should be able to create any unpleasant substance or mild (This is a cantrip, after all) poison with this use of Prestidigitation.

Possible uses of this function could include creating bat guano for the material component of fireball, or turning water into wine as alcohol is a type of mild poison.

What constitutes Mild Poison depends on your DM. A strict DM might say that it can only be strong enough to affect role play, and must have no monetary value. A more lenient DM might rule that you can create low quality alcohol or make some/all of the damage of your weapon be poison damage. Honestly it’s better to talk about this with your DM in advance.